# Is there a formula to capture all the values from one sheet (excluding blanks) and show it in the order on another?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Bit of a tricky question. I'm having the columns F:K  with the numbers in Sheet1

Is there a excel formula to copy all the values from sheet 1 excluding blanks and display them in Column B in sheet2 .

The order of displaying them in sheet 2 in column B should be horizontal so if any values in F2;G2;H2;I2;J2;K2 F3;G3;H3;I3;J3;K3 and so on should be display in that order

Columns with the numbers
[image: Columns with the numbers]

So the expected output in sheet2 should be as folow

[image: Output]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The excluding blanks bit is difficult - not excluding blanks you could use `=INDEX(Sheet1!F:K, FLOOR.MATH(ROW(B1)/6+5/6), MOD(ROW(B1)-1, 6)+1)` in cell B1 and copy down

Comment: Show your expected output. What is your excel version? `TEXTJOIN()` may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    AggregateToColumnWithoutBlanks DataRange:=Range("A2:F4"), OutputStart:=Range("H2")
End Sub

Public Sub AggregateToColumnWithoutBlanks(ByVal DataRange As Range, ByVal OutputStart As Range)
    Dim DataCells As Range
    Set DataCells = DataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
    If DataCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no data found
    
    Dim Output() As Variant
    ReDim Output(1 To DataCells.Count, 1 To 1) As Variant
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In DataCells.Cells
        iRow = iRow + 1
        Output(iRow, 1) = Cell.Value
    Next Cell

    OutputStart.Resize(RowSize:=UBound(Output, 1)).Value = Output
End Sub
```

Loop through all cells with constant values `xlCellTypeConstants` if there are formulas you might need to adjust this. And collect them in an array that you can easily output in a range.

Comment: I salute you Sir. Worked like a dream @PEH

Comment: how could I adjust the above for the range with the formulas in the cells please?
i have changed the DataCells type to xlCellTypeFormulas type but it pulls the output with the blanks.

Comment: When you say there are blanks to these blanks contain a formula? Because then they are not blank. Blank means the have no content not even a formula.

Comment: you are correct there is a column which contain vlookup formula. I would like to use above code to transfer those this column also(excluding blanks). You said it yourself 
"if there are formulas you might need to adjust this. And collect them in an array that you can easily output in a range."?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function on the internet that is equivalent to PHP implode function which does what you want.
https://www.alunr.com/excel-vba-equivalent-of-the-php-implode-function/

```
Function IMPLODE(Rng As Range, Sep As String)
    Dim TEMP As String
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell.Value = "" Then
        Else
            TEMP = TEMP & Cell.Value & Sep
        End If
    Next Cell
    TEMP = Left(TEMP, Len(TEMP) - Len(Sep))
    IMPLODE = TEMP
End Function
```

And it becomes a function in the workbook to use.
In L2:

```
=IMPLODE(F2:K2,";")
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas seems like a perfect solution however I'm on excel 2013 and IMPLODE function isn't available for me

Comment: It's not available for anyone except those who add the code in the answer to a module in VBA editor

Comment: Anyway it does not what was asked for. See the expected output screenshot.

Comment: That was edited after I wrote this answer. But stil the question says: `should be horizontal so if any values in F2;G2;H2;I2;J2;K2 F3;G3;H3;I3;J3;K3`.